# Is it possible to show the package version of a dependency?

Tags: javascript, npm

I `yarn add some-package@2.3.4`, and in my JS code

```
import * as s from 'some-package';
```

Is there a way to show in my code the version of the imported `some-package`, namely 2.3.4?

I would like to know if it's possible in browser and in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the `package.json` file from the dep, like this:

```
import pkg from 'some-package/package.json'
```

Version should be there under the `pkg.version` key.

Or:

```
import { version } from 'some-package/package.json'
```